# Decide if it is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given D = {p$\in$$P_n$ : p'(1)=1} decide if this is a vector space.

My thoughts is that if you have p'(1)=1 it should not be certain that we can find a p(x)=0 which is one of the criteria of vector spaces. However I'm not sure if this is correct and if so, how I can prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p(X)$ is the null polynomial, then $p'(0)=0\ne1$. So, $p(X)\notin D$ and therefore $D$ is not a vector subspace of $P_n$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a vector space because even the zero element is not in this set. Also, your notation is too vague for people to understand.